# How do multiclass characters' Nonweapon Proficiency slots advance?

Tags: skills, adnd-2e, character-advancement

I would like to know, if possible, how a multiclass character non weapon proficiency works after level 1. In the players handbook its not clear at all. It just states:

> If the optional proficiency system is used, the character starts with the largest number of proficiency slots of the different classes. Thereafter, he gains new proficiency slots at the fastest of the given rates. To determine the character's initial money, roll according to the most generous of the character's different classes.

I would appreciate if anyone here could tell me if there is some kind of official answer from the game producers or something that could be considered "official".

It would be best if you could post a link from the page containing the answer that I'm looking for.

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Pretty good first question. Didn't get put on hold, and barely edited at all. Feel free to roll back other people's edits and make your own improvements, everybody's trying to be helpful. If you have any meta questions about policy or how questions ought to be formed, please don't hesitate to ask on [Meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 5):

The answer is directly contained in your quote.

> Thereafter, he gains new proficiency slots at the fastest of the given rates.

This means that you look at Table 34, Proficiency Slots on p.71 (revised printing) and see that the different class groups get different numbers of initial proficiencies (weapon and nonweapon) and also gain one at every N levels, where N is also different per class group. If you are a Warrior/Rogue, for example, the best NWP slot advancement of those two classes is 1 NWP every 3 levels, so that's the rate of NWP advancement you use.

Comment: But, is that 3 levels of *both* or *either*? And, what if the quicker NWP progression has higher XP per level?

Comment: Reread the 2e multiclassing rules. XP is always divided evenly across the character's classes. Hit points are the only thing "divided by classes," so a Warrior3/Rogue3 would have 6 total levels for the purpose of NWPs and thus have gained 2 from advancement.